# ArcGIS iteration naming

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder

I'm trying to use the iteration function in ArcGIS model-builder. To avoid overwriting the output raster, I used %Name% inline variable. But the name of my files are getting bigger and bigger overtime (I use the outputs in another set of iterations). Is there a way to select only part of the file name and not all of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the model only calculate value tool to create the name you desire. This would require you to write a small bit off python to do a bit of string manipulation.